# (SCSS-CSS) &:hover CSS method codepen

Tags: html, css, sass, hover, megamenu

I have found this template in **codepen** website and i just want to create the mega-menu following this template . however i don't know how to use SCSS is there 
a method to create a "mega-menu" using Css instead. i think that the code responsible for this is **&:hover** so is there any code like this in CSS ("note":"i don't want this code :hover

visit: https:// codepen. io/jayanudin/pen/groxYe?depth=everything&order=popularity&page=3&q=dropdown+hover&show_forks=false

Comment: `selector { &:hover }` is equivalent to `selector:hover`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&:hover` is just appending a `:hover` selector to the parent.

```
.parent {
    &:hover {}
}
```

Is the same as

```
.parent:hover {}
```

Comment: does that mean that .menus-megamenus {
  &:hover .mega-menus {
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible; 
  }
 }is equivalent to .menus-megamenus .mega-menus:hover { opacity:1; visibility:visible;}

Comment: The hover goes on the parent, so it is .menus-megamenus:hover .mega-menus {}